# How can I clear the IP address of Ethernet interface without cycling the interface up/down or restarting it

Tags: linux, networking

What is the Linux command to clear IP addresses of an interface without bringing it down and/or restarting network services?

Seems strange that `ifconfig` is able to change IP addresses but has no option to remove them, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Andy: I think you misunderstood the question. @jackhab wants to unassign an address from the interface, not set it to `0.0.0.0` -- it's just how it is done with `ifconfig`.

Comment: @grawity Cheers. Unassigning an address is switching the NIC off to all intents and purposes?

Comment: @Andy: Not necessarily. One could still watch incoming packets. Also, a NIC can have multiple addresses (though it doesn't apply in this case).

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/407676/deleting-all-ips-on-an-interface-with-iproute2

Comment: To clear the IPs of all interfaces that are `up` you can use `ip addr flush up`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As simple as `ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0`. They should have put it in the manual.

Answer (score 186):

Use `ip` from iproute2. (You need to also specify the prefix length though.)

```
ip addr del 10.22.30.44/16 dev eth0
```

To remove all addresses (in case you have multiple):

```
ip addr flush dev eth0
```

Comment: Works, but when I do want to a non-dev permanent change, I get an error saying "eth0 is garbage" (lol). i guess i need to manually edit that file, just can't remember the name right now

Comment: When setting up a kubernetes cluster I accidently ran a command that created an interface and used an IP address that was being used so I needed to delete that IP address but leave the interface around.  This command fixed my problem.  I used `sudo ip addr del 192.168.0.1/24 dev weave`.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646326/how-do-i-remove-an-ip-address-from-an-interface

Answer (score 18):

To remove all adreses from all interfaces i used for loop:

```
for i in $(ls /sys/class/net/) ; do
    /usr/sbin/ip addr flush $i &
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are just looking to get a new IP from the [DHCP-enabled] router? In this case call

`dhclient eth0`

Comment: THAT worked, whereas assigning an IP didn't somehow get the network working.  Thank you.

Comment: The only problem here is that now you coulld have two ips assigned as `dhclient` just asks for one more IP not checking if one is already there nor deleting the old ips. So delete the unused IP first before you call `dhclient`